# PHP or/xor operator isn't working like expected

Tags: php, operators, xor

```
/* Create Theme Rules */
if($selectedTheme=='spring' or 'framed' or 'art' or 'champagne'){
  echo 'yes';
}
```

I have this scripting that *should* only take place if the `$selectedTheme` equals one of the above, but it does it on every theme. This works fine:

```
  if(
    ($selectedTheme==('spring') or 
    ($selectedTheme==('framed')) or 
    ($selectedTheme==('art')) or 
    ($selectedTheme==('champagne')))
   )
     { echo 'yes'; }
```

But that seems like a lot of unnecessary code.
What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: I'd handle it like bwoebi said below. Your first doesn't work because comparison doesn't work as you've got it. `if($selectedTheme == 'spring' || 'art')` essentially evaluates to `if($selectedTheme == 'spring' or TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above you cannot do; it simply evaluates as `$selectedTheme=='spring' or true or true or true`.

A shorter, less redundant version would be:

```
if (in_array($selectedTheme, ['spring', 'framed', 'art', 'champagne'])) // PHP 5.4 syntax (use array(...) if you have PHP 5.3 or lower)
```

You also could use a switch with no breaks and a lot of cases:

```
switch ($selectedTheme) {
    case 'spring':
    case 'framed':
    case 'art':
    case 'champagne':
        // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression:

```
if ($selectedTheme == 'spring' or 'framed' or 'art' or 'champagne')
```

is using an interpretation of English `or` that is shared by relatively few programming languages.  The arguments to `or` are usually independent, so the above is asking if either the selected theme is equal to `'spring'`, or the string `'framed'` is (of its own accord) true, or the string `'art'` is true, or the string `'champagne'` is true.  Since any non-empty string is true in PHP, the expression as a whole is always true.

There are lots of ways to avoid the repetition of the longer-form `if`; the simplest is probably `in_array`, as @bwoebi suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Look at evaluation of:

```
($selectedTheme==('spring') or 
($selectedTheme==('framed')) or 
($selectedTheme==('art')) or 
($selectedTheme==('champagne')))
```

It does actually:

1. compare `$selectedTheme` to `'spring'`, if its `true` whole expression is true, otherwise
2. compare `$selectedTheme` to `'framed'` - if its `true` whole expression is true, otherwise,
3. compare `$selectedTheme` to `'art'`, if its `true` whole expression is true, otherwise
4. compare `$selectedTheme` to `'champagne'` - if its `true` whole expression is true, otherwise, expression is `false`,

while:

```
 ($selectedTheme=='spring' or 'framed' or 'art' or 'champagne')
```

does:

1. compare `$selectedTheme` to `'spring'`, if its `true` whole expression is true, otherwise,
2. if `'framed'` is `true` return `true` - non-empty string is resolved as true when used as boolean, thus whole expression is always true.

As a result Your former code is always true, while the latter works as You expect. Programming languages are kind of strict and You shouldn't rely on mental leaps unless language's definition openly allow it. Shorter replacement was presented by @bwoebi.